# Упорядоченная вставка элементов в QTableView

Tags: qt, c++

Доброго времени суток!

Ситуация такая:
Использую QTableView для отображения состояния входного потока данных. Т.е. у меня отключены вертикальный и горизонтальный заголовок, а элемент "Таблицы" представляет собой ячейку с парой данных PID/LID и цветом. Получается, что у столбцов и строк нет никаких названий, они ни за что не отвечают.
Перед первым добавлением данных в таблицу я изначально просто сортирую массив с пидами/лидами и последовательно добавляю их в таблицу. Таблица получается отсортированной, сначала идут ячейки с PID==0, отсортированные по LID, далее с PID==1 и т.д.
Реально ли вообще реализовать упорядоченную вставку? Без сортировки изначального массива, и чтобы затем можно было вставлять ячейки в таблицу с сохранением упорядоченности? Или, может, для таких целей вообще что-то другое следует использовать?
Спасибо!

Comment: Вы сначала код покажите, как вы вставляете данные в таблицу?

Answer (score 2):

QTableView - это как раз то, что реализует роль "представление" в концепции "модель-представление-контроллер". По сути, сам объект класса не содержит никаких добавляемых Вами данных, все эти данные содержит "модель", которая реализуется в наследниках QAbstractItemModel.

В вашей ситуациии есть 2 выхода. Первый - включить [сортировку в QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#sortingEnabled-prop); при таком подходе не имеет никакого значения, в каком порядке и в какое место Вы будете вставлять данные в модель, ведь за их отображение конечному пользователю отвечает не модель, а представление. Второй - добавлять данные в модель изначально упорядоченно.

Comment: Еще можно использовать промежуточную модель QSoftFilterProxyModel.